# Circle Progress View like activity app

Tags: ios

I am trying to create an animated radial chart that looks like the activity app created by Apple. I provide an image to show what I would like as result:

[image: Example]

Do you know how to obtain this result? If you have any idea could you please focus on the following points?

1. Create the gradient inside each circle
2. Create the shadow on the head of the circle

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Check out my custom control, I tried to make it as close as possible to the Activity app design, and everything is customizable.

https://github.com/maxkonovalov/MKRingProgressView

---

The basic idea behind the algorithm is quite simple.

**To draw arc line with changing color:**

1. Generate a conical gradient image

[image: Conical gradient]

You can use a prerendered image from Photoshop or generate your own dynamically. I use a gradient image generator from here: https://github.com/maxkonovalov/MKGradientView.

2. Clip gradient image to show only the arc

[image: Clipped gradient]

```
CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
CGContextAddPath(ctx, arcPath)
CGContextClip(ctx)
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, gradientRect, gradientImage)
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
```

**Drawing the shadow is even simpler:**

1. Draw shadow behind your progress arc (shown with 50% opacity here)

[image: Shadow]

I draw a circle shape matching arc's end for the shadow.

```
CGContextSetShadow(ctx, offset, shadowRadius)
CGContextAddPath(ctx, shadowPath)
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, shadowColor)
CGContextFillPath(ctx)
```

2. Clip the shadow to fit into the progress circle

[image: Shadow clipped]

```
CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
CGContextAddPath(ctx, circlePath)
CGContextClip(ctx)
// Draw shadow...
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
```

And the final result looks like this:

[image: Circle progress view]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Luke: Updated my answer with more details on the algorithm

Comment: I don't think the shadow will show once it reaches 100% or more. The shadow won't cover the red area once the blue area reaches say 130%, which it does in the Apple Watch screenshot in the question.

Comment: @GrahamPerks that's true, to make it work the same way as Apple Watch app requires a few hacks not covered here for simplicity. It all works as expected though in the lib I linked at the top of my answer, you can check the source for more details on the implementation.

Comment: @maxkonovalov Thank you for the great answer. Can you elaborate on how to deal with the progress being over 100%?

Comment: @wcandillon The algorithm is as follows: the gradient arc is always drawn up to a certain angle, until the shadow intersects with the arc's start (about 90% progress). After that (90-100% progress), the whole gradient arc is rotated, and another arc filled with start color is drawn below, which allows to make the ring feel wrapped over itself. For progress values greater than 100% the whole ring is just rotated. For more details take a look at MKRingProgressView's implementation.

Comment: Yes, I managed to crack it thank you! It was hard to see "this trick". The code is available at https://github.com/wcandillon/can-it-be-done-in-react-native/tree/master/season3/src/AppleActivity, I've done a video about it that is scheduled to be released tomorrow at https://www.youtube.com/user/wcandill

Comment: @maxkonovalov thank you for paving the way with that animation.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you need as it appears to generate the image for you, but you could get some good info from the source.

https://github.com/hmaidasani/RadialChartImageGenerator

Comment: I already found that but it's just a tool to generate a set of images to be used for the AppleWatch.
I need to create the progress for an iOS application (iPhone).