# Apple Workout Rings SpriteKit Animation

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, watchos-2

I am trying to re-create the Apple Workout Rings in my WatchOS App. I am making use of SpriteKit and GameScene for the animation. However, I am not able to understand how to implement the overlapping rings and include a gradient.

[Workout Rings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcgGy.jpg)

I tried using SKShader in order to incorporate the gradient effect. However, SKShapeNode ignores the line cap when SKShader is present so I'm not able to get the rounded edges.

I have also looked at other approaches like : [Circle Progress View like activity app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481516/circle-progress-view-like-activity-app)

However, I don't know how to use this approach for the watchOS as SpriteKit works on the concept of nodes and this approach deals with CGContext.

```
    class GameScene: SKScene {

    func circle(radius:CGFloat, percent:CGFloat) -> CGPath {

        let start:CGFloat = 0
        let end = ((CGFloat.pi * 2)) * percent
        let center = CGPoint.zero
        let corePath = CGMutablePath()
        corePath.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: start, endAngle: end, clockwise: true)
        return corePath
    }
    // Animated Timer for Progress Circle
    func countdownCircle(circle:SKShapeNode, steps:Int, duration:TimeInterval, completion:@escaping ()->Void)  {
        guard let path = circle.path else {
            return
        }
        let radius = path.boundingBox.width/2
        let timeInterval = duration/TimeInterval(steps)
        let increment = 1 / CGFloat(steps)

        var percent = CGFloat(1.0)
        let animate = SKAction.run {
            percent -= increment
            circle.path = self.circle(radius: radius, percent:percent)
        }
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration:timeInterval)
        let action = SKAction.sequence([wait, animate])
        run(SKAction.repeatForever(action)) {
            self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration:timeInterval/2)) {
                circle.path = nil
                completion()

            }

            //(action,count:steps-1)
        }
    }
    // Animated Timer for Shadow Circle
    func countdownShadow(circle:SKShapeNode, steps:Int, duration:TimeInterval, completion:@escaping ()->Void)  {
        guard let path = circle.path else {
            return
        }
        let radius = path.boundingBox.width/2
        let timeInterval = duration/TimeInterval(steps)
        let increment = 1 / CGFloat(steps)
        var percent = CGFloat(1.0)
        let animate = SKAction.run {
            percent -= increment
            circle.path = self.circle(radius: radius, percent:percent)
        }
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration:timeInterval)
        let action = SKAction.sequence([wait, animate])
        run(SKAction.repeatForever(action)) {
            self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration:timeInterval)) {
                circle.path = nil
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
//(action,count:steps-1)

override func sceneDidLoad() {

    let pathForCircle = CGMutablePath()
    pathForCircle.addArc(center: CGPoint.zero, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

    // This is the circle that indicates the progress.
        let progressCircle = SKShapeNode()
        progressCircle.lineCap = .round
        progressCircle.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 15)
        progressCircle.strokeColor = SKColor.green
        progressCircle.lineWidth = 20
        progressCircle.path = pathForCircle
        progressCircle.zPosition = 4
        self.addChild(progressCircle)
        countdownCircle(circle: progressCircle, steps: 400, duration: 5){
            print("Done")
        }

    // This is the circle that gives the ring the shadow effect.
        let shadowCircle = SKShapeNode()
        shadowCircle.lineCap = .round
        shadowCircle.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 15)
        shadowCircle.strokeColor = SKColor.black
        shadowCircle.glowWidth = 30
        shadowCircle.zPosition = 3
        shadowCircle.path = pathForCircle
        self.addChild(shadowCircle)
        countdownShadow(circle: shadowCircle, steps: 400, duration: 5){
            print("Done")
        }

    // This is the bottommost circle.

        let bottommostCircle = SKShapeNode()
        bottommostCircle.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 15)
        bottommostCircle.lineCap = .butt
        bottommostCircle.strokeColor = SKColor.green
        bottommostCircle.alpha = 0.2
        bottommostCircle.lineWidth = 20
        bottommostCircle.path = pathForCircle
        bottommostCircle.zPosition = 0
        self.addChild(bottommostCircle)

}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

there are plenty of Spritekit implementations of this exact sort on GitHub

Here is one that looks particularly good.

https://github.com/HarshilShah/ActivityRings